# Parse ls output using sed to get file location of files with specific names

Tags: sed, awk, ls

To start with, I know this way is quite not the right one, as often mentioned [why shouldn't I parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but it is a part of my university project (so I could use sed and awk along).

I have to find files which names start with a given string. I stared with listing the current directory using `ls`:

```
ls -LR1
```

which gives me the example output:

```
.:
bin
etc
games
include
lib
man
sbin
share
src

./bin:
apt
gnome-help
highlight
mint-sha256sum
pastebin
search
szukaj
yelp

./etc:

./games:

./include:

./lib:
python2.7
python3.5

./lib/python2.7:
dist-packages
site-packages

./lib/python2.7/dist-packages:

./lib/python2.7/site-packages:

./lib/python3.5:
dist-packages

./lib/python3.5/dist-packages:

./man:

./sbin:

./share:
ca-certificates
emacs
fonts
man
sgml
xml

./share/ca-certificates:

./share/emacs:
site-lisp

./share/emacs/site-lisp:

./share/fonts:

./share/man:

./share/sgml:
declaration
dtd
entities
misc
stylesheet

./share/sgml/declaration:

./share/sgml/dtd:

./share/sgml/entities:

./share/sgml/misc:

./share/sgml/stylesheet:

./share/xml:
declaration
entities
misc
schema

./share/xml/declaration:

./share/xml/entities:

./share/xml/misc:

./share/xml/schema:

./src:
```

Now I want to use `sed` or possibly `awk` to get to get files with names starting with given string, lets say `'Do'`. I would like to achieve something like this:

1. `sed` (or `awk`?) parses each line and searches for line that starts with `'Do'`
2. If there is a match, moves to previous line and searches for . (which is an indicator for relative path), if there's no match jumps to the line before and so on
3. Prints the line as relative path:`.path/filename`

Is it even possible to achive?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `find . -name 'Do*'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of `find` existence, however as stated in OP, I am required to use `sed` and/or `awk`.

Comment: Show your teacher ["The Evolution of a Programmer."](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html)  Then tell your teacher to come up with some better example use cases for text processing; there are literally thousands of cases where `sed` or `awk` are the *correct* tools for the job.  Finding files isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, let's consider these files:

```
$ ls -LR1
.:
a

./a:
b

./a/b:
bad
Do_good
```

Now, let's find the file that you want:

```
$ ls -LR1 | awk '/^\.\//{sub(/:$/, "/", $0); dir=$0} /^Do/{print dir $0}'
./a/b/Do_good
```

**How it works:**

- `/^\.\//{sub(/:$/, "/", $0); dir=$0}`

  Every time that we find a line that begins with `./`, we replace the find `:` with a `/` and update the variable `dir`
- `/^Do/{print dir $0}`

  Every time that we find a line that begins `Do`, we print the variable `dir` followed by this line.

**Limitation:** As you are aware, the output of `ls` is intended to be human-readable and parsing it is unreliable.  This code is only for purposes of demonstrating the use of `awk`.  It should not be used for anything serious.

#### Preferred method -- 1

As [wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard) pointed out, `find` is the right tool for this task:

```
$ find . -name 'Do*'
./a/b/Do_good
```

#### Preferred method -- 2  (requires bash)

In bash, as [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) points out, one can recursively search for files using the globstar feature:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
printf '%s\n' **/Do*
```

Comment: Or `printf '%s\n' **/Do*` in shells that supports `**`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, very good.  Thank you.  A globstar solution has been added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, you'd use the hold space to store the path of the last seen directory:

```
sed -n '
  /^\..*:$/{
    h;d
  }
  /^Do/{
    G
    s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\):|\2/\1|p
  }'
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution which uses `sed`!